# gallery / click image, replace it with new image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, replace, click

i did research for some hours but i can't find anything that is close enough to what I'm looking for. if you know a similar topic, please post the link.

i have not much experience with/in js. i want to create a small simple gallery. 
i have a single image on the website. On click the image should be replaced by another one (image2). when i click now on this one, it should be replaced by image3 and so on. 
i tried following but this doesn't work at all.

JS

```
$('.image1').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image2.jpg');
    $(this).addClass('image2');
});

$('.image2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'image3.jpg');
    $(this).addClass('image3');
});
```

…
when i get the last image (for example "image10"), the gallery should go to the start (image1).

thx for your help

Comment: show us the final html please

Comment: It would be really good to make your function more generic though so that when clicking on any image, it runs the same fucntion and gets the next image name from the current image name by incrementing the number, for example.

Comment: @Bartdude the problem is event delegation

Comment: Use a CSS only image gallery! http://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-css3-galleries-collection/

Comment: @Alex > Yes indeed, as the element doesn't have class `image2` in the beginning, the event isn't set so basically it can only work with the first image. I have editted my remark...

Answer (score 0):

Write something like this. You don't need 10 different event handlers.

Create a common class .. for instance `imageClass`

```
$(document).on('click', '.imageClass', function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src'); //image1.png
    var index = src.split('.')[0].replace('image',''); //get index `1`
    //add 1 to index or reset to first image
    index = (index == "10") ? 1 : parseInt(index) + 1;
    $(this).attr('src', 'image' + index + '.jpg');
});
```

Comment: thats a really bad way of getting the index

Comment: @Alex - well.. you could use regex, but I'm not good at it :)

Comment: index() does not even make sense. use regex or lastindexof() combined with substring...

Comment: `.slice(-1)` will never equal 10!

Comment: why wouldnt it make sense? you put in all the images, show only the first one and you use length and index to make the slider dynamic and working

Comment: @gulty - since we don't know what OP has on his webpage, we cannot assume all the images are already loaded. If they are already loaded and markup is in an indexable fashion, then I think `.index()` makes sense.

Comment: `var match = src.match(/\w+(\d+)\.jpg/)` will give you the index on a regex match at `match[1]`

Comment: the `\d+` matches 1 or more digits, so yes

Comment: Sorry, should be `/[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)\.jpg/`  `\w` matches letters and numbers (`var match = src.match(/[a-zA-Z]+(\d+)\.jpg/)`)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something called a Carousel, you have plenty opensource implementations of them on github. One of the most used is Lightbox : https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js

Code is not very long, and you should 'easily' (between quotes :p) find part of it you need for your page.

Answer (score 0):

To show using index() does indeed make sense here you go:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Svc9L/1/)

JS Code

```
$('.image').first().show();
$('.image').on('click', function () {
  target = $('.image:visible').index();
  lastElem = $('.image').length -1; //2 cause 3 images..
  target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
  $('.image').hide()
  $('.image').eq(target).show();
});
```

All images besides the first are initially hidden.

Comment: youre assuming that for each src an image will exist, since it does not index() does not make sense.

Comment: the op's code isn't working. this is one way to make it work. he can of course use regex if he wants to stick with the current markup. but he can also choose this way to solve his problem :)

Comment: but not with the markup being available. you cant use an index() function if there is only one element, therefore you have to use string methods. there are no images, just one which src changes. how is index possible then?

Comment: You don't have to explain the use of string methods over and over again. The question was how he can make the slider work. Not how he can make the slider work without changing the markup. You want to tell me that solutions should be JS solutions only? There is no problem to just add the images to the markup. It's a solid solution for his problem. Of course the index() method is no option with 1 image only but nobody said it's not allowed to add them all to the html.

Comment: But the OP said he has only 1 image in his markup. When you just provide JS code using index you should at least provide the advice to add html else your answer simply isnt applicable. period.

Comment: Well, I added a JSFiddle where you can see the html used. I could add it as well as the css but imo people should be able to use their brains in case they want people to help them out..

Comment: yeah, thx for your help.
actually i have only one image in my markup. i don't want to add more pictures. Is it possible just to change the url of the image by clicking on it?